# Clearest definition of a limit

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the most elegant and clearest definition of limit that you know?

For me is this:

Let $f(x)$ be a function defined on an interval that contains $a$, except possibly at $a$.  Then we say that:

$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=l$

if for every number $\varepsilon>0$ there is some number $\delta>0$ such that:

$\lvert f(x)-l\rvert<\varepsilon $

whenever:

$0<\lvert x-a\rvert<\delta $

Comment: I think that's the definition which most people are familiar with.

Comment: This is, indeed, the definition of limit that has withstood the test of time.  But do you really think this is clear?  Try explaining it to 100 18-year-olds in freshman calc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just the usual definition for finite limit $l$ with x which tends to a finite cluster point $a$.

Note that as an alternative someone set that $x\neq a$, in this case it suffices that $\lvert x-a\rvert<\delta$.

Comment: Correct me if wrong . |x-a| < Delta , takes care of all cases, I.e. x  \in Domain of f, and x  not \in Domain of f. The x-y| < Delta is fine , possibly a confusion with Delta >0?

Comment: @PeterSzilas I was not so precise, I fix my statement.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit biased, but my favourite definition of the limit is from nonstandard analysis.

> Let $f(x)$ be a function on a punctured interval $(r, s) \setminus \{a\}$. Let $^*f$ be the transfer of this function to the hyperreals. We say $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = l$ if, whenever $x$ is infinitesimally close to $a$, $^*f(x)$ is infinitesimally close to $l$.

Comment: IMO, this is a non-answer. It requires preliminary knowledge of *nonstandard analysis*,  *transfer*, *hyperreals*, *infinitesimally*... which are unfamiliar to many, and involve much more than the initial question.

Comment: To be frank, I am currently studying Keisler's Infinitesimal Calculus and the only difference I find compared to other usual calculus books is that the author has convinced (by using temrs like Transfer Principle, standard part etc) that words like "infinitesimals" have rigorous basis without actually providing the rigorous justification of these new terms. This is perhaps smarter than other authors but still no better if one wants a theory of calculus.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=l$ if by restricting $f$ to an appropriate punctured neighbourhood of $a$ you can fit its image into any neighbourhood of $l$.

- This works for every topological space, not just for real numbers.
- It uses terms whose meaning for real numbers (and some more general spaces) is intuitively easy to grasp, and therefore supports both an intuitive and a rigorous level.